# Rails - Associations - Automatically setting an association_id for a model which has 2 belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models

```
class User < ...
  belongs_to :language
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ...
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ...
  has_many :users
  has_many :posts
end
```

Im going to be creating lots of posts via users and at the same time I have to also specify the language the post was written in, which is always the language associatd with the user i.e.

```
@user.posts.create(:text => "blah", :language_id => @user.language_id)
```

That's fine but the way I set the language doesn't sit well with me. The language will always be that of the users so is there a 'best-practice' way of doing this?

I know a little about callbacks and association extensions but not sure of any pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a 'good practice' way involving callbacks.

```
class Post
  before_validation_on_create :set_language

  protected
  def set_language
    self.language ||= self.user.language if self.user
  end

end
```

Then, you can

```
@user.posts.create(:text => "blah")
```

or

```
post.create(:text => "fewf")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just make a `create_post` function in the user model:

```
def create_post(text)
  posts.create(:text => text, :language_id => language_id)
end
```

then just call it where ever you need.